# Excel is interpreting date wrong

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem. I have data in this format:

13.3.19 00:23:01

I use a macro to import it to one tab, copy it to another tab, and replace the "." with "/" so it in the correct format. But excel said no and interprets most of the data as text, which is not a problem, I just use datevalue on that. But when it comes to this date in particular:

12.3.19 23:52:41

Excel is interpreting it as a date in the US format and instead of leaving it as march the 12th, it makes December the 3rd out of it. This renders the datevalue useless in just a part of my data set.

Any thoughts?

Code of the macro here:

```
Sub import_data()


Path = Worksheets("Macro").Cells(6, 4).Value
Analysis = ThisWorkbook.Name

Rfrom = Sheets("Macro").Cells(8, 4)
Rto = Sheets("Macro").Cells(9, 4)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False


 For Data_Range = Rfrom To Rto

Fname = Sheets("Macro").Cells(Data_Range, 3)
Segment_name = Sheets("Macro").Cells(Data_Range, 4)

'selecting workbook
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        Path & "\" & Fname _
        
    Sheets(Segment_name).Select
    
    Range("A2:W14000").Select
    Selection.Copy
        
    Windows(Analysis).Activate
    Sheets("Raw_data_import").Select
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
    Windows(Fname).Activate
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Windows(Analysis).Activate
        
    
        
Next Data_Range

Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Activate
Sheets("Raw_data_import").Activate
Range("E:G").Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Priprava_dat").Select
Range("A:C").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
Sheets("Priprava_dat").Range("A:B").Replace ".", "/"


Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & lastRow)
    Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E" & lastRow)
    Range("F2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F" & lastRow)
    Range("G2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G" & lastRow)
    Range("H2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H" & lastRow)
    Range("I2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("I2:I" & lastRow)
    Range("J2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J" & lastRow)
Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Activate
Sheets("Macro").Activate
        

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set the number format of the cells using

```
Sheets("Priprava_dat").Range("A:B").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss"
```

just before changing the '.' to '/' using

```
Sheets("Priprava_dat").Range("A:B").Replace ".", "/"
```